# $X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\sim$ is closed in $X \times X$

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces, separation-axioms

$X$ is a Hausdorff space and $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

If the quotient map is open, then $X/{\sim}$ is a Hausdorff space if and only if $\sim$ is a closed subset of the product space $X \times X$.

Necessity is obvious, but I don't know how to prove the other side. That is, $\sim$ is a closed subset of the product space $X \times X$ $\Rightarrow$ $X/{\sim}$ is a Hausdorff space. Any advices and comments will be appreciated.

Comment: I wonder if we can remove the condition that the quotient map is open. In that case, necessity is also obvious, is the sufficiency also true? Or is there any counterexamples?

Comment: @Jingren: You should post this as a separate question. Anyway: Yes, the condition that the quotient map be open is necessary. Consider $X/A$ where $X$ is a non-regular Hausdorff space and $x$ is a point that cannot be separated from the closed set $A$. In the quotient $X/A$ the image of the point $x$ can't be separated from the point corresponding to $A$ while the equivalence relation is obviously closed.

Comment: @yaoxiao Very nice post.

Comment: @t.b. You could post this as an answer to the new question http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1903343/give-an-example-of-a-non-compact-hausdorff-space-such-that-delta-is-closed-bu

Comment: Is the result still true if the quotient map is not open?

Answer (score 24):

Since the map $\pi:X\to X/\sim$ is open, it's clear that the map $g:X^2\to (X/\sim)^2$ given by $g(x,y)=(\pi(x),\pi(y))$ is open. What we claim is that $g(X^2-\sim)=(X/\sim)^2-\Delta_{X/\sim}$. Indeed, if $x\nsim y$ then $\pi(x)\ne\pi(y)$ which tells us that $g\left(X^2-\sim\right)\subseteq (X/\sim)^2-\Delta_{X/\sim}$. That said, if $(\pi(x),\pi(y))\notin\Delta_{X/\sim}$ then $\pi(x)\ne \pi(y)$ so that $x\nsim y$ so that $(x,y)\in X^2-\sim$ and clearly $g(x,y)=(\pi(x),\pi(y))$. Thus, $g(X^2-\sim)=(X/\sim)^2-\Delta_{X/\sim}$ as claimed. But, since $X^2-\sim$ is open by assumption, and $g$ is an open map we have that $(X/\sim)^2-\Delta_{X/\sim}$ is open, and so $\Delta_{X/\sim}$ is closed. This gives us $T_2$ness.

Answer (score 16):

Let $R$ be the subset of $X \times X$ which gives the equivalence relation $\sim$, and let $f\colon X \to X/{\sim}$ be the quotient map. Let $x, y \in X$ be points not equivalent under the relation, i.e. $(x, y) \notin R$. Since $R$ is closed and $X \times X$ has the [product topology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Product_topology#Definition), there exist open sets $U, V$ in $X$ such that $(x, y) \in U \times V$ and $U \times V$ does not meet $R$. Can you separate $f(x)$ and $f(y)$ using $U$ and $V$? Remember that $f$ is assumed to be an open map.

[This is a lot like the proof of the fact that Alex is using: that a space $X$ is [Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal is closed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hausdorff_space#Equivalences) in $X \times X$.]

Answer (score 8):

Let $Y$ be the quotient. This is a question about the diagonal $D$ in $Y\times Y$.

Note that the product map $X\times X \to Y \times Y$ is also a quotient map (this is where open-ness is needed), and that your set $\sim$ is precisely $(\pi\times\pi)^{-1}(D)$. Thus $\sim$ is closed if and only if $D$ is closed.

Now, $D$ is closed if and only if $Y$ is Hausdorff, for *any* topological space $Y$. This follows by considering disjoint neighborhoods $U$ and $V$ of any two distinct points $p$ and $q$: $(p,q)\in U\times V$ which is open and disjoint from $D$, so $D^c$ is closed. Conversely, the closedness of $D$ implies the existence of some product open set $U\times V$ disjoint from $D$ and containing $(p,q)$, and thus $U$ and $V$ are open sets separating $p$ and $q$.

Answer (score 7):

Let $\pi:X\to X/\!\!\!\sim\;$ denote the projection map associated with $\sim$.  (That is, for any $x\in X$, $\pi(x)$ is the $\sim$-equivalence class that $x$ belongs to.)  Let $\nsim\; \subseteq X \times X$ be shorthand for the complement of $\;\;\sim\;\;$ in $X \times X\;$, i.e. $\nsim\;\;=\;(X \times X\;) \;\;-\; \sim\;$.

Suppose that $\pi(x) \neq \pi(y)\;$.  (Here I'm relying on the fact that, since $\pi$ is surjective, any element $\widetilde{z}\in X/\!\!\!\sim\;$ may be written in the form $\pi(z)$, for some $z \in X$.)  We must show that there exist open sets $U_{\pi(x)}, U_{\pi(y)} \subseteq X/\!\!\!\sim\;$ such that ${\pi(x)} \in U_{\pi(x)}$, ${\pi(y)} \in U_{\pi(y)}$, and $U_{\pi(x)} \cap U_{\pi(y)} = \varnothing\;$.

By assumption, $\;\sim\; \subseteq X \times X$ is closed, so $\nsim\; \subseteq X \times X$ is open.  Therefore there exist open neighborhoods $N_x$ and $N_y$ of $x$ and $y$, respectively, such that $(x,\;y)\in N_x \times N_y \subseteq$$\;\;\nsim\;$.  (This is because the family of all pairwise products of open subsets of $X$ is a basis for the product topology on $X \times X$.)

For any $v, w \in X$,

$$
(v,\;w) \;\in \;\nsim \;\;\;\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\;\;\;
\pi(v) \neq \pi(w)\;\;.
$$

Therefore,

$$
N_x \times N_y \subseteq \;\;\nsim\;\;\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\;\;
\forall (v, w) \in N_x \times N_y \;[\pi(v) \neq \pi(w)] \;\;\;\;\Leftrightarrow\;\;\;\;
\pi[N_x] \cap \pi[N_y] = \varnothing
$$

Furthermore, since $\pi$ is open (by assumption), the image sets $\pi[N_x], \pi[N_y] \subseteq X/\!\!\!\sim\;$ are open neighborhoods of ${\pi(x)}$ and ${\pi(y)}$, respectively.  Therefore, $\pi[N_x]$ and $\pi[N_y]$ are the desired open neighborhoods $U_{\pi(x)} \ni {\pi(x)}, U_{\pi(y)} \ni {\pi(y)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Start with a point $(x,y)$ with $x$ and $y$ not related. Then, as the relation is reflexive, it contains the diagonal. Now, as the relation is closed, its complement is open and there is a neighbourood of $(x,y)$ which does not intersect it. Next think about what a base for the product topology might look like...

Answer (score 0):

Since $X$ is Hausdorff, this implies that $X \times X$ is Hausdorff. If the quotient map is open, $g: X \times X \to X/{\sim} \times X/{\sim}$ such that $ g(x,y) = (\pi(x),\pi(y)) $ is surjective, continuous and open. So $ g $ itself is a quotient map. Since $ X \times X$ is Hausdorff, $ \sim = g^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed in $X \times X $ iff  $\Delta$ is closed in $ X/{\sim} \times X/{\sim}$, where $\Delta$ is the diagonal set. Thus, $ \Delta \subset X/{\sim} \times X/{\sim}$ is closed $  \implies \  X/{\sim} \times X/{\sim} $ is Hausdorff $\implies \  X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff.