# $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal of $X\times X$ is closed

Tags: general-topology, separation-axioms, product-space

> Let $X$ be a topological space. The **diagonal** of $X \times X$ is the subset $$D = \{(x,x)\in X\times X\mid x \in X\}.$$
>   Show that $X$ is Hausdorff if and only if $D$ is closed in $X \times X$.

First, I tried to show that $X \times X \setminus D$ is open using the fact that $X \times X$ is Hausdorff (because $X$ is Hausdorff), but I couldn't find an open set that contains a point outside $D$ and is disjoint to it...

Comment: One part is [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/95819/diagonal-delta-x-times-x-x-in-x-closed-in-x-times-x-implies-tha) and a generalization of this question can be found [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x).

Comment: you should add that topology on $X \times X$ is product topology

Answer (score 127, accepted):

You have two things to show: that if $D$ is closed, then $X$ is Hausdorff, and that if $X$ is Hausdorff, then $D$ is closed.

Suppose first that $D$ is closed in $X\times X$. To show that $X$ is Hausdorff, you must show that if $x$ and $y$ are any two points of $X$, then there are open sets $U$ and $V$ in $X$ such that $x\in U$, $y\in V$, and $U\cap V=\varnothing$. The trick is to look at the point $p=\langle x,y\rangle\in X\times X$. Because $x\ne y$, $p\notin D$. This means that $p$ is in the open set $(X\times X)\setminus D$. Thus, there must be a basic open set $B$ in the product topology such that $p\in B\subseteq(X\times X)\setminus D$. Basic open sets in the product topology are open boxes, i.e., sets of the form $U\times V$, where $U$ and $V$ are open in $X$, so let $B=U\times V$ for such $U,V\subseteq X$. Can you see how to use this to get the desired open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$?

Now suppose that $X$ is Hausdorff. To show that $D$ is closed in $X\times X$, you need only show that $(X\times X)\setminus D$ is open. To do *this*, just take any point $p\in(X\times X)\setminus D$ and show that it has an open neighborhood disjoint from $D$. I suggest that you try to reverse what I did above. First, $p=\langle x,y\rangle$ for some $x,y\in X$, and since $p\notin D$, $x\ne y$. Now use disjoint open neighborhoods of $x$ and $y$ to build a basic open box around $p$ that is disjoint from $D$.

Comment: Suppose that $U$ is a neighborhood of $x$, $V$ is a neighborhood of $y$, then $U\times V$ is open and contains in $X\times X\setminus D$. How can I show that $X\times X\setminus D$ is open from that?  (because I think that a closed set can contains open set)

Comment: @Arsenaler: A set is open if it contains an open nbhd of each of its points. The argument of the last paragraph shows that $(X\times X)\setminus D$ contains an open nbhd of each of its points.

Comment: If $\left(U\times V\right)\cap\Delta=\phi$ can we immediately conclude that $U\cap V=\phi$?

Comment: @JEM: Yes: if there were some $x\in U\cap V$, then $\langle x,x\rangle$ would be an element of $(U\times V)\cap\Delta$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott  "Can you see how to use this to get the desired open neighborhoods of x and y?"  Not really.  I follow everything up to this point.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Tim: Since $\langle x,y\rangle\in U\times V$, we have $x\in U$ and $y\in V$. If there were a point $z\in U\cap V$, then $\langle z,z\rangle$ would be in $U\times V$. But $B\cap D=\varnothing$, so this is impossible.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you

Comment: @Tim: You’re welcome.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Sorry one more question.  How do you know that $B \cap D = \emptyset$?

Comment: @Tim: Because $B$ was chosen to miss the diagonal: $B\subseteq(X\times X)\setminus D$. We can do this because the diagonal is closed.

Comment: In the first part how do we know there exists distinct a x and y? What if X has 0 or 1 elements?

Comment: @kmecpp: If $|X|\le 1$, the diagonal is either empty or $X\times X$, so it’s automatically closed (and $X$ is vacuously Hausdorff).

Answer (score 22):

There is a related problem:

> Let $f,g:A\to B$ be two continuous maps, $B$ is a Hausdorff space and $A$ is an arbitrary space. Then the set $C(f,g)=\{x\in A| f(x)=g(x)\}$ is the *coincidence set* of $f$ and $g$. Prove $C(f,g)$ is closed.

to proof this, for every point $x_0$ not in $C(f,g)$,  $y_f=f(x_0)$ and $y_g=g(x_0)$ are two distinguished point in $B$, because $B$ is Hausdorff, you get two disjoint open neighborhood $U(y_f)$ and $U(y_g)$, because $f,g$ is continuous, $O=f^{-1}(U(y_f))\cap g^{-1}(U(y_g))$ is open in $A$. You can verify that $O$ is a neighborhood of $x_0$ disjoint of $C(f,g)$, for if $c\in C(f,g)$ and $c\in O$, then $c\in f^{-1}(U(y_f))$ and $c\in g^{-1}(U(y_g))$, this is equal to say $f(c)=g(c)$ is in both $U(y_f)$ and $U(y_g)$, which is impossible because the two neighborhood is disjoint.

Set $A=X\times X$, $B=X$, $f=\pi_1$, $g=\pi_2$ be the projection map, you get the desired result.

Hope this can illustrate the problem you ask.

Comment: Do you mean [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3201722/continuous-mapping-into-a-hausdorff-space) one?

Answer (score 14):

Let $(x,y)\in X\times X$, with $x\neq y$. Since $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$, and $X$ is Hausdorff, there exist open set $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ such that $x\in\mathcal{U}$, $y\in\mathcal{V}$, and $\mathcal{U}\cap\mathcal{V}=\varnothing$. Now, $\mathcal{U}\times\mathcal{V}$ is an open subset of $X\times X$. It contains $(x,y)$. Does it intersect $D$?

Conversely, suppose $D$ is closed, and let $x,y\in X$, $x\neq y$. Then $(x,y)\notin D$, so there is an open subset $\mathscr{O}$ such that $(x,y)\in\mathscr{O}\subseteq X\times X - D$. Do you know something about open sets of a special type in $X\times X$ that might let you obtain open sets of $X$ $\mathcal{U}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ as in the previous paragraph?

Comment: Suppose it didn't intersect $D$, why would I care?

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman If you are asking about the first paragraph: you care because, *presumably*, you are trying to prove that $D$ is closed. So you are trying to find an open set that contains $(x,y)$ and does not intersect $D$, in order to show the *complement* of $D$ is open. What wasn’t clear about that?

Comment: Many answers are actually going there and then stop, as if I'm unaware of some very well-known criterion for openness. It looks like they're all using a result like: "If $U⊆ X$ is open, and $U ∩ D = \emptyset$, then $D$ is closed." I have no idea where this comes from (but, to be honest, I've been out of topology for a while).

Comment: So I guess my question is: how would an open containing $(x, y)$ disjoint from $D$ prove that $X × X \setminus D$ is open..? From my point of view, you only show that $X × X \setminus D$ _contains_ an open.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman: No, that’s not what is happening. A set $U$ is open if and only if for every $x\in U$ there exists an open neighborhood $V$ of $x$ (a set $V$ that is open and contains $x$) such that $V\subseteq U$. A set is closed if and only if its complement is open. So you can prove that $D$ is closed by showing that for every $x\notin D$, there is an open set $V$ that contains $x$ and does not intersect $V$. It’s not a **single** open set $U$, it’s a set $V_x$ that depends on $x$: one for every point in the complement.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman: Your point of view is incomplete. What was proven is that **for every** point $(x,y)$ in the complement, there is an open set that contains the point and is contained in the complement. Once you put all those open sets together, *then* you conclude the complement is open, and hence the set is closed.

Comment: @JosvanNieuwman: The result being used is: “If **for every** $\mathbf{x}\notin D$ there exists an open set $U\subseteq X$ such that $\mathbf{x}\in U$ **and** $U\cap D=\varnothing$, then $D$ is closed.”

Answer (score 10):

Let X be Hausdorff, then if $x\ne y$ there are neighborhoods $V_x$ and $V_y$ such that $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$. Therefore $V_x\times V_y \cap D=\emptyset$ and the complement of $D$ is open. Now, assume that the latter is true. Then, for any point $(x,y)$, $x\ne y$, there is an open set around it that does not intersect $D$. Therefore, there are two sets $x\in V_x$ and $y\in V_y$ such that $V_x\times V_y$ doesn't intersect $D$, therefore $V_x \cap V_y = \emptyset$.