# $f:M\to N\times N$ is continuous and $\Delta = \{(y,y):y\in N\}\subset N\times N$ then $f^{-1}(N\times N-\Delta)$ is an union of open balls in $M$

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, metric-spaces

I need to show the following:

$f:M\to N\times N$ is continuous and $\Delta = \{(y,y):y\in N\}\subset N\times N$ then $f^{-1}(N\times N-\Delta)$ is an union of open balls in $M$

But I have no idea of which things I must assume. I know that if I can prove that its open, then its automatically an union of open balls. However, I've read [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1437391/prove-that-f-1n-times-n-triangle-is-a-union-of-open-ball-in-m) that it suffices to show that $N\times N-\Delta$ is open. Is this it? And why does it follows that the inverse is open?

Comment: Related: [$X$ is Hausdorff if and only if the diagonal of $X\times X$ is closed](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136922/x-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-the-diagonal-of-x-times-x-is-closed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An equivalent definition of continuity is that the inverse image of every open set is open. In fact, many people would take that as the true definition of continuity!

So if $N\times N-\Delta$ is open then the result follows.

Now it is open if and only if $\Delta$ is closed. The latter is easy to show. Take a sequence in it that converges and show the limit is in it too.