# $\Delta = \{(x,x), x\in M\}\subset M\times M$. Show that if $z\in M\times M - \Delta$ then there is a ball with center $z$, disjoint from $\Delta$

Tags: metric-spaces

I need to show this:

$\Delta = \{(x,x), x\in M\}\subset M\times M$. Show that if $z\in M\times M - \Delta$ then there is a ball with center $z$, disjoint from $\Delta$

I need to use the metric $d(z,z') = max\{d_i(x_i, x_i'), i\in \{1,2\}\}$ where $z = (x_1, x_2)$ and $z' = (x_1', x_2')$ for the set $M\times M$. Note that $d_i$ is the metric on $M$.

First of all: WHY would someone ask something like this? I tried to imagine $\Delta$, which could be understood, in the plane, as the set of points $(x,y)$ in which $x=y$. And I Inderstand $z\in M\times M - \Delta$ as the plane without the line $x=y$. I understand the metric of this space as being the greatest distance: the horizontal one or the vertical one.

Now, I can construct an open ball, in my mind, in this metric space. But how do I prove it, and why is this important?

In order to prove, I'd try to construct an open ball with center in  $b\in  M\times M - \Delta$, to begin with my argument. Then, what argument can I use to prove that no element inside my ball will touch $\Delta$? Why is the metric, as defined that way, useful?

Comment: It's related to the condition of being Hausdorff.  A space is Hausdorff iff the diagonal is closed in the product.  See this [question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136922/x-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-the-diagonal-of-x-times-x-is-closed)

Comment: This metric is called the $\ell^\infty$ metric.  It's a very common metric.  See this [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L-infinity).

Comment: The reason this is important is that it is an exercise designed to strengthen your mathematical muscles. In particular, this exercise, if successfully completed, will strengthen your triangle inequality muscle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: Let $z=(z_1,z_2)\in M\times M\setminus\Delta$.  Let $a=d_M(z_1,z_2)$.  Consider the ball of radius $\frac{a}{4}$ centered at $z$.  Could this ball intersect the diagonal?  Suppose, for contradiction, that it does, then $(w,w)$ is in the ball.  Now, use the triangle inequality to derive a contradiction.

More details: Since $(w,w)$ is in the ball, $d_M(z_1,w)<\frac{a}{4}$ and $d_M(z_2,w)<\frac{a}{4}$.  But then, $d_M(z_1,z_2)\leq d_M(z_1,w)+d_M(z_2,w)<\frac{a}{2}$, which is a contradiction.

Comment: hmmm, what a radius $a/4$ helps in?

Comment: You need any radius less than $\frac{a}{2}$ for the contradiction to work.  It's a constant that "falls out" of the contradiction (it's not obvious when you start, but once you've worked through the contradiction, you'll see where it becomes necessary).

Comment: I'm confused. I' ve found arguments not using the metric at all: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136922/x-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-the-diagonal-of-x-times-x-is-closed but I can' t do this one you're trying to tell me.

Comment: Sure, you could use the argument that you linked to.  First, you need to show that $M$ is Hausdorff which uses essentially the proof that I highlighted above, and *then* you can follow what's in that link.  Or, you can just prove it all at once...

Comment: could you give me a geometric interpretation for this? :c

Comment: The more details section really covers the geometry.  Think about the point $(1,2)$.  If you have a point $(w,w)$ thatis close to $(1,2)$, then the change from $1$ to $w$ or the change from $2$ to $w$ is at least $1/2$ (by the triangle inequality).  Moreover, if you consider the ball of radius $1/4$, then the first coordinate can vary in $(3/4,5/4)$ while the second coordinate can vary in $(7/4,9/4)$.  Observe that the two intervals overlap, so there is no point of the form $(w,w)$ in this ball.