# $X$ Hausdorff and Compact, $f: X \rightarrow X$ continuous. Is the set of fixed points of $f$ Compact?

Tags: general-topology

I'm trying to prove the following statement:

> If $X$ is a Compact, Hausdorff Topological Space and $f:X\rightarrow X$ is a continuous function, then the set $F=\left\{ x \in X : f(x) = x\right\}$ of fixed points of the function
>   $f$ is Compact.

Yet any clues on how to even start.

Comment: There's an easy approach if $X$ is a vector space, which is to say that we can note the continuity of $x \mapsto f(x) - x$.  I'm not sure if that argument generalizes in any way

Comment: @Omnomnomnom It's a very beautiful way of prooving the result for vector spaces, since $\{0\}$ is closed. I also coundn't think of a way to generalize it, but I would be very happy if is there's any simple way to proof this general version. ;p

Comment: This also generalizes to arbitrary metric spaces, in which $x \mapsto d(f(x),x)$ is continuous.  If a counterexample exists, it must be non metrizable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The set of fixed points is closed in $X$. This is because it is
the inverse image of the diagonal
 $\Delta=\{(x,x):x\in X\}\subseteq X\times X$
under the continuous map $x\mapsto (x,f(x))$
from $X$ to $X\times X$. Note that $\Delta$
is closed in $X\times X$ due to the Hausdorff property.

As the fixed points are a closed subset of a compact space, they also
form a compact space.

Comment: +1. To the OP: There is a common problem in a first course on point-set topology, that says: Prove that a topological space $X$ is Hausdorff **iff** the diagonal of $X \times X$ is closed. You can find it posed/discussed in [**MSE 136922**](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/136922). $$ $$ (Proving any closed subset of a compact space is compact is a common problem, too!)