# Proving that the diagonal in Reals is closed

Tags: general-topology

> Let $\mathbb{R}^2 := \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}$ have the product topology (where $\mathbb{R}$ has the standard order topology). 
>   Let $D = \{(x,x) | x \in \mathbb{R}\}$ be the diagonal in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that $D$ is closed in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Here, its all in Reals. I did it using Hausdorff but I cant use that. My prof said show that using if its complement (i.e. $D^C$) is open then $D$ is closed or using some other technique.

Below is what I did, please check and let me know if there is anything wrong or if it require a better notation. Thanks!!

[image]

Comment: So make an effort to show the complement is open. What precisely must you prove?

Comment: What did you try? Where are you getting stuck?

Comment: Can you show that $f(x,y) = x-y$ is continuous?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true for Hausdorff spaces but got the reals you can give a quite easy argument if you know that open segments like $(a,\rightarrow) =\{x \in \Bbb R: x > a\}$ and $(\leftarrow,a)=\{x \in \Bbb R: x < a\}$ are open:

Suppose $(x,y) \notin D$ so $x \neq y$. Suppose WLOG that $x < y$ and pick $z$ so that $x < z < y$, then $(\leftarrow,z) \times (z,\rightarrow)$ is open in $\Bbb R^2$ (in the product topology), contains $(x,y)$ and misses $D$: otherwise $(w,w) \in (\leftarrow,z) \times (z,\rightarrow)$ would imply $w < z$ and $w > z$ which cannot both be true.

Comment: I got your proof, I have few questions to ask you abt open segments, whats the difference b/w open intervals and segments? We didn't have this in our notes we only did open intervals, half open intervals and closed intervals. Does a segment have similar meaning as interval ?

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun an open segment has only one bound: it’s of the form $\{x\mid x < a\}$ or $\{x\mid x > a\}$ for some $a$ in the ordered set. An interval has two bounds, say $a< b$, and consists of all points in between.

Comment: ok, got it now. :)

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun The definition of the order topology is that all open segments are open, open intervals are then also open as $(a,b)=(a, \rightarrow) \cap (\leftarrow,b)$ etc. a min or max of an ordered set cannot lie in an open interval, but does lie in open segments of one of the types. Hence their slightly different local bases.

Comment: yeah, order topology says that its generated from a sub-basis that consists of union of positive and negative open rays, and wat u did here is an open interval. Anyway, would u mind checking my proof? I updated this Q with my proof, you can see that on the top. Kindly let me know if it needs a better notation or if there is something wrong.

Comment: @Math_Is_Fun Your proof is fine. You can suffice with the open segments as I did. No need for $\varepsilon$ and disjoint intervals. I only need that there is a $z$ between $x$ and $y$. It generalises to all ordered spaces (if no such $z$ exists, we take slightly different open segments (or open rays, as they're also called). I like concise and to the point proofs.

Comment: ok, what if I use $\epsilon$, will it be a matter of grave concern?

Answer (score 0):

You sort of need to use that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff because $X$ is Hausdorff iff the diagonal in $X^2$ is closed.

I guess you are to show essentially this equivalence. You can do this by showing the compliment is open.

See [this SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136922/x-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-the-diagonal-of-x-times-x-is-closed)

Comment: I didnt get u. Wat equivalence are u talking about?

Comment: That X is Hausdorff iff diagonal closed.