# What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}$ with the $K$ topology and $\mathbb{R}_k$?

Tags: general-topology

I am studying the $K$ topology and struggling with some of the basics...

1. My first question is the question in my title.  What is the difference between $\mathbb{R}$ with the $K$ topology and $\mathbb{R}_K$?  I think they are one and the same...correct?  That means it is a collection of all open intervals along with all open intervals with unit fractions removed.
2. My second question is about the definition of the $K$ topology (although it is not really a question).  It seems strange to me - just append a bunch of additional sets to the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$.  I suppose there is not much to understand about a definition...it just it, but it seems unnatural to me compared to other topologies we have studied (lower limit, order).  Are there any comments to help me understand this?
3. I know $K$ is not closed in $\mathbb{R}$ because it does not contain its limit point $0$.  Is $K$ closed relative to the $K$ topology because its complement is open (open intervals)?

I can prove the $K$ topology is strictly finer than the standard topology but will also want to discuss Hausdorff, connected (possibly path-connected), and compact.  I am hoping some basic clarification of the above topics will assist me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: How is $\Bbb R_{K}$ defined in your notes?

Comment: As quoted from Munkres, "When $\mathbb{R}$ is given this topology, we denote it by $\mathbb{R}_K$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes. $\mathbb{R}_K$ is just notation for the topological space $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_K)$, where $\tau_K$ is the $K$-topology with basis $\{(a, b): a, b\in \mathbb{R}\}\cup\{(a, b)\setminus K : a, b\in \mathbb{R}\}$.
2. Its purpose is to be weird and unnatural: to have odd properties, so it can serve as a counter-example to some intuitive but false conjectures one might propose. It should seem unnatural because it is unnatural.
3. Yes. $K=\{\frac{1}{n} : n \mbox{ is a natural number } >0\}$ is not closed in the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, but is closed in the $K$-topology, for the reasons you stated.

Comment: Oh yay!  Thank you so much Marcel!  I am new-ish to topology and have a hard time wrapping my brain around some of the information.  Even if I think I am right, I doubt myself!

Comment: @fullyhip: One can use the $K$-topology to show that a square of quotient maps need not be a quotient map, see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820329/the-topology-on-x-sim-times-x-sim-is-not-induced-by-pi-times-pi/1056353#1056353