# Hausdorff topology on $X/\sim$: Confusion in a proof

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space, and $\sim$ be an equivalence relation on $X$. Let $\pi:X\rightarrow X/\sim$ be the natural surjective set map. Put quotient topology on $X/\sim$ w.r.t. the topology on $X$ and the surjection $\pi$.

Let $\Delta$ be the diagonal of $(X/\sim)\times (X/\sim)$.

Now,

(Topology on $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff) $\Longleftrightarrow$ ($\Delta$ is closed in $(X/\sim)\times (X/\sim)$) $\Longleftrightarrow$ ($(\pi\times\pi)^{-1}(\Delta)$ is closed in $X\times X$).

**Q.1** Is the second equivalence correct (due to quotient topology)?

Next, $(\pi\times\pi)^{-1}(\Delta)=\{(x,y):x\sim y\}$. Call relation $\sim$ on $X$ closed if
$\{(x,y):x\sim y\}$ is closed subspace of $X\times X$. So, the above equivalence says:
$$
(\mbox{Topology on $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff}) \Longleftrightarrow (\sim \mbox{ is closed relation on $X$})
$$
**Question 2:** Is this last assertion correct?

In the book Homology theory by Vick, the author proves:

> *If $\sim$ is closed relation on compact Hausdorff space, then  quotient topology on $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff*

I am confused why compactness is needed, since in above arguments, it does not appear. Why can't we say from above equivalence that if $\sim$ is closed relation, then quotient topology on $X/\sim$ is Hausdorff? I confused to understand my fault in proof-or-statement understanding.

Comment: You are assuming that the product topology is induced by the projection map times itself. This is not necessarily true. It is true if the projection is open, e.g., when the space is compact.

Comment: Can you elaborate more first line? (You may state in form of result; I will try to prove it.)

Comment: See here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x?noredirect=1&lq=1   and here  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/820329/the-topology-on-x-sim-times-x-sim-is-not-induced-by-pi-times-pi

Comment: @vap: Thanks very much for the important links; that is really helping to catch my fault.