# If an equivalence relation is compact on a compactum then its quotient is Hausdorff?

Tags: general-topology, quotient-spaces

I'm currently reading [this](https://www.ams.org/journals/tran/2006-358-07/S0002-9947-06-03928-6/S0002-9947-06-03928-6.pdf) article and in the proof of Lemma 4.3 the authors write the following (here $R^D$ is just the notation for an equivalence relation over $D$):

"... *compactness of $R^D$ easily implies that $D/R^D$ is Hausdorff.*"

I have tried to prove this with no success at all, but my approach is trying to prove it without the aditional hypothesis given in the Lemma, like this:
If $X$ is a *compactum* (i.e. compact and Hausdorff) and $R$ is an equivalence relation over $X$ which is compact on $X\times X$ then the quotient $X/R$ is Hausdorff. (?)

What I know so far is that each equivalence class must be compact, the quotient map is closed and
I've found [this result](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x) which solves the problem when te quotient map is open.
Any help would be aprreciated.

Comment: $R^D$ would indeed be closed in $X \times X$ (because $X \times X$ is Hausdorff and a compact subset is closed in a Hausdorff space) and then the linked question would solve your issues. But I see that that assumes $q$ is open as well, and this is not clear.

Comment: Indeed, if it were the case that $q$ is open, then there is nothing to do but in general we can't say that $q$ will be open.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wow this is indeed a true statement. I was surprised by how this is not mentioned in basic topology textbooks.

*Proof:* Suppose $[x],[y]$ are distinct equivalence classes. Since the relation is compact, the classes are also compact and since $X$ is $T_4$, $[x]$ and $[y]$ can be separated by two disjoint open sets, say $U$ and $V$, respectively. Now, we already know that the quotient map $q\colon X \to X/R$ is closed and Proposition 2.4.9 of Enegelking's book on general topology states the following:

*For an equivalence relation $E$ over $X$ the following statements are equivalent*:

*1. The quotient map is closed.*

*2. For every open set $A\subseteq X$ the union of all equivalence classes that are contained in $A$ is open in $X$.*

We can take the union of all equivalence classes contained in $U$ and the union of all equivalence classes contained in $V$ to be $R-$saturated disjoint sets that contain $[x]$ and $[y]$ respectively. This gives that $X/R$ is Hausdorff.