# The Hausdorffification of a compact space comes from the smallest closed equivalence relation on X?

Tags: general-topology

Given a topological space $X$, there are a Hausdorff topological space $SX$ and a continuous map $\pi:X\to SX$ such that, if $Y$ is a Hausdorff space and $f:X\to Y$ a continuous map, there exists a unique continuous map $\bar f:SX\to Y$ such that $f=\bar f\circ\pi$.

Prove that, if $X$ is compact, $\{(x,x')\in X\times X\mid \pi(x)=\pi(x')\}$ is the smallest closed equivalence relation on $X$ (closed as a subset of the topological space $X\times X$).

This was stated in Banaschewski's paper, "On Lattices of Continuous Functions," which I want to read in order to understand projective ordinal sums of Heyting algebras.

Answer (score 1):

Denote by $P=\{(x,x')\in X\times X\ |\ \pi(x)=\pi(x')\}$. I leave as an exercise that $P$ is an equivalence relationship.

First I will show that every closed equivalence relationship contains $P$.

*Proof.* Assume that $R\subseteq X\times X$ is a closed equivalence relationship. Consider the quotient space $X/R$. It is well known that it is Hausdorff ([$X/{\sim}$ is Hausdorff if and only if $\sim$ is closed in $X \times X$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/91639/x-sim-is-hausdorff-if-and-only-if-sim-is-closed-in-x-times-x)). Now consider the projection

$$p:X\to X/R$$
$$p(x)=[x]$$

Since $X/R$ is Hausdorff then we can apply properties of $\pi$: there is a unique continuous map $\overline{p}:SX\to X/R$ such that $p(x)=\overline{p}(\pi(x))$. It follows that if $\pi(x)=\pi(x')$ then $p(x)=p(x')$. In other words if $(x,x')\in P$ then $(x,x')\in R$. Which is what we wanted to prove. $\Box$

Now we will show that $P$ itself is closed.

*Proof.* Assume that $(u,v)\in (X\times X)\backslash P$. In particular $\pi(u)\neq \pi(v)$ and since $SX$ is Hausdorff then there are two open, disjoint neighbourhoods $U$ of $\pi(u)$ and $V$ of $\pi(v)$ in $SX$. Since these are disjoint then so are $\pi^{-1}(U)$ and $\pi^{-1}(V)$, and in fact $\pi(x)\neq \pi(y)$ for $x\in \pi^{-1}(U)$ and $y\in \pi^{-1}(V)$. This shows that $\pi^{-1}(U)\times \pi^{-1}(V)$ is an open neighbourhood of $(u,v)$ disjoint from $P$. By the arbitrary choice of $(u,v)$ we conclude that $(X\times X)\backslash P$ is open, and so $P$ is closed. $\Box$

Now since $P$ is closed and contains every other closed equivalence relationship, then $P$ has to be the smallest one among them.

Note that $X$ being compact is irrelevant in all of this.